# Gallery image background

Tags: android, drawable, android-gallery

I set a background image in android gallery with:

```
ga.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.myimage);
```

and it's work. 
How can i set the position of background image in android gallery ?

**DETAILS**:
I have a semi-trasparent gallery of image over a background image.
So I need to center the image in the gallery over the background image.
NOT full width image.

If it's impossible to do, how can i set an image over a selected image from gallery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the background image since you know the selected image in the gallery using `gallery.getSelectedItemPosition()`

Using this position you should be able to get the image from the images list that you provide to the gallery's adapter

for example if it's a list of drawables:

```
 imageView.setImageDrawable(listDrawables.get(gallery.getSelectedItemPosition()));
```

as for centering part you should just set

```
 <ImageView
      ...
      android:scaleType="centerInside"
      ... />
```